# ToggleButtons in react bootstrap won't reset

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik, togglebutton

Hello I am trying to make a component out of react bootstrap toggle group buttons using formik, the component works and pass the data correctly, but it just won't reset the buttons to "no button pressed at all" when I reset the form (the last pressed button is still checked,although the value of the togglebuttons being null(as intended)).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.scss";
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from "react-bootstrap";

const ToggleButtonsGrp = (props) => {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(props.state);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.formik.setFieldValue(props.formName, JSON.parse(toggleValue));
    props.formik.setFieldTouched(props.formName);
  }, [toggleValue]);

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      id="toggleButtonGroup"
      name="toggleButtonGroup"
      className="toggleButtonGroup"
      onChange={(value) => setToggleValue(value)}
    >
      {props.toggleButtons.map((opt) => (
        <ToggleButton
          key={opt.name}
          id={`toggle-${opt.name}`}
          type="radio"
          name={props.formName}
          className={`toggleBtn ${
            opt.value === toggleValue ? "toggleBtn-Off" : "toggleBtn-active"
          }`}
          checked={opt.value === toggleValue}
          value={opt.value}
        >
          {opt.name}
        </ToggleButton>
      ))}
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
};
```

tried to add a useEffect like this:

```
   const [update,SetUpdate] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => {
    if(!props.state) //when it resets or first time
       setUpdate(update+1) //this would force a rerender
  }, [props.state]);
```

It didn't solve the problem so I removed this.

The external form looks like this:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={someFieldName:null}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          ...//some logic
          resetForm()
          ...
        }}
>
{(formik)=>(
...
   <ToggleButtonsGrp
                  toggleButtons={SomeButtons}
                  formName="someFieldName"
                  state={formik.values.someFieldName}
                  formik={formik}
   />
..
)}
</Formik>
```

while SomeButtons built like:

```
[{
   name:"someName",
   value:"someValue"

},
{
   name:"someName2",
   value:"someValue2"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I don't need to reset the form, leaving it if someone wants a challenge.
Sadly can't close the question myself.